# Only show UI image on iphone 11 hide it on other iphone versions

Tags: swift, iphone, swift3, storyboard, uikit

Using Storyboards how can I show an UI image only on a specific iphone version and hide it on other iphone versions like iphone 8 for example?
Is this possible in swift?

Answer (score 1):

Using Storyboard you could show/hide the image based on size classes, here's the [Apple Documentation for it](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html). The caveat with this approach is that multiple devices are part of the same size class. To see which devices belong to what size classes [check this link](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/), and scroll down to the **Size Classes** section.

If you want to be device specific, you'll need to write it in code. It's a bit more complex to do it, but there's a really good [library for it](https://github.com/schickling/Device.swift). It's a one file implementation, so if you don't care for Pods or similar tools, you can just copy the file in your project, or maybe even decipher it and come up with your custom implementation.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. Will be taking a look at this!